# PHP while loop with 'or' condition always stops at higher value

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a while loop with 2 conditions separated by 'or':

```
while (($i <= 8) || ($x <= 5)){
  $i++;
  $x++;
}
```

I want the loop to end when the lowest number is reached - in the above case 5. However, the above stops when the first, higher condition is met and it loops 8 times.

This still occurs when I swap the values, eg:

```
while (($i <= 5) || ($x <= 8))
```

The loop will still ignore <= 5 and loop through 8 times.

Would anyone know how I can fix this to have the loop cycle stop at the lower number?

Comment: Thats not enough code to debug your problem.

Comment: Try AND instead of OR, because what you need is that if one of condition is false, you have to stop.

Comment: @tkausl there's nothing really more to it. Just counters within the while loop of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's doing what you have written.  Use `&&` instead of `||` and it will stop as soon as one of the conditions is no longer true.

Comment: Ah thanks. I thought && was when both conditions were met. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: It is when both conditions are met.  It seems that's what you're after.. keep doing X until one of these conditions isn't met == keep doing X while both conditions are true

Answer (score 3):

The loop will execute as long as the expression inside `while(expression)` is true. In this case, your expression is `$i <= 8 || $ x<=5` wich translates into:

$i is less or equal than 8 **OR** $i is less or queal than 5.

From php documentation:

> $a || $b  is TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.

If you want the smallest number, then you want both conditions to be true to continue the loop, so you use **AND**, which documentation is:

> $a && $b is TRUE if both $a and $b are TRUE

So your code should be:

```
while (($i <= 8) && ($x <= 5)){
  $i++;
  $x++;
}
```

You can also use the keywords `and`and `or`, but be careful, because they have different operator precedence, in particular, they have less precedence:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `and` instead of or

```
while (($i <= 8) && ($x <= 5)){
}
```

If you use or it needs only one of its condition to be true for foing inside the loop. And will ensure that both of the condition should be true. So it will exit the loop when any one of the condition becomes false

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'and' operation.

```
while($x<5 && $y<8) {//Your code here}
```

I suggest reading about this logic operators, these operators are basic in development.